# How to add multiple instances to an Amazon VPC using AWS CloudFormation without auto scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am playing around with AWS CloudFormation and I have it working with creating a single instance and in another manifest it working with auto scaling however I don't quite need the full power of autoscaling. is it possible to add a param to say I want **X**   amount of instances and it just adds that amount into the VPC with all the relevant metadata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

There is no "NumberOfInstance" property, so you have to just create multiple resources with the type `AWS::EC2::Instance` and assign them to your subnets inside your VPC.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative approach to this is also to use a 3rd party lib like [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) to generate your cloudformation templates. If the instances you are creating are similar, you can use iteration or call a function with params to generate and add the objects to the template in significantly less lines of code than cut and pasting the json fragments. They are arguably more maintainable at that point.

Beware if adding a lot of instances and using the console you can start to hit limits on either the size of the template or the number of objects within it. In the prior case you have to move to the CLI to do the create.